# Getting first one depending on the current row

Tags: sql, oracle, join

There are three tables, such as `equip_type`, `output_history`, and `time_history` in Oracle DB. How to join the three tables as shown below?
(DBMS: Oracle)

```
 EQUIP MODEL DATE1  QUANTITY   DATE2   TIME  EQUIP_TYPE
 ---- ---- ---------- ------  -------- ----  ----------
  e1    m1  20180103  10      20180101   6    A
  e1    m1  20180106  20      20180105   5    A
```

Notice that at the point of `DATE1` `'20180103'` in `output_history`, `DATE2` `'20180101'` in `time_history` is the most recent one.

At the point of `DATE1` `'20180106'` in `output_history`, `'DATE2 20180105'` in `time_history` is the most recent one.

```
--equip_type table and the date
CREATE TABLE equip_type  (  
  EQUIP_TYPE VARCHAR(60),    
  EQUIP VARCHAR(60)
  );
INSERT INTO equip_type  VALUES ('A','e1');

-- output_history and data
CREATE TABLE output_history (  
  EQUIP VARCHAR(60),     
  MODEL VARCHAR(60),     
  Data1 VARCHAR(60),        
  QUANTITY  NUMBER(10) 
  );
INSERT INTO output_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180103',10);
INSERT INTO output_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180106',20);


--time_history table and data
CREATE TABLE time_history (  
  EQUIP VARCHAR(60),     
  MODEL VARCHAR(60),       
  Data2 VARCHAR(60),    
  time NUMBER(10)
  );
INSERT INTO time_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180101',6);
INSERT INTO time_history VALUES ('e1','m1','20180105',5);
```

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: "at the point of DATE1 '20180103' in output_history, DATE2 '20180101' in time_history is the most recent one" is not clear. You are not clearly explaining what the output should be given the input.

Comment: Oracle dbms I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery with a `NOT EXIST` condition to select the closest related record in `time_history`.

I tested below query on MySQL in [this db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bn2qBz8GSJ5u1pxLh6UU3C/0). You did not tag the RDBMS you are using. I tested on MySQL, but this is standard SQL that will work on  most RDBMS.

```
SELECT
    o.equip,
    o.model,
    o.data1,
    o.quantity,
    t.data2,
    t.time,
    e.equip_type
FROM 
    output_history o
    INNER JOIN equip_type e ON e.equip = o.equip
    INNER JOIN time_history t ON t.equip = o.equip AND t.data2 <= o.data1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM time_history
    WHERE 
        equip = o.equip
        AND data2 <= o.data1
        AND data2 > t.data2
)
```

Sid notes : the query will be always lookup the most recent `time_history` record *before* the current `output_history` record (even if there is a closest record in the future, it will not be selected)

Disclaimer : don't store dates as strings, this is a recipe for disaster. Use the relevant datatype according to your RDBMS. In your use case, it works only because dates are formated in a way that they can be easily sorted.